# How can I tell if a Django session is new?

Tags: django, session

Within a view, is there an easy way to tell if this is the very first hit in a session?

I looked for something obvious like comparing session-create-date to session-last-accessed-date, but those fields don't seem to exist.

I could set a custom key in the session data, and then if the key is missing assume it's a new session, but I wondered if there were some cleaner way.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - detect session start and end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083426/django-detect-session-start-and-end)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

How about you calculate it via [`settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age) minus [`my_session.get_expiry_age()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age). The closer to 0, the newer the session. Not sure though this is always zero for a first-hit session.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too.  But like you say, the difference isn't guaranteed to be zero for a new session.

Comment: Except this I don't see a built-in way to do it. You might be able to find a workaround, extending session model (db sessions) or saving session creation somewhere else. Another idea is to save a flag in the session (on creation), a boolean or something which you toggle first time the session is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the session_key. If request.session.session_key is None, that means the session object is new and hasn't been saved to the db yet.