# How to trigger an action on session timeout in Django

Tags: django, session

I wonder how I could trigger an action whenever a session timeout occurs. Is there a way to set up a callback function that would be executed before the session data get destroyed? I need a solution that also works for unauthenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the default session database backend, you can use a Django signal to detect when a session is deleted from the DB, following an approach similar to this:

[Django - detect session start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083426/django-detect-session-start-and-end)

Note that in Django 1.5+ the command to use is [clearsessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-clearsessions), and not cleanup.

For more details you can refer to the official documentation on [clearing the session store](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store).

If the cronjob configuration is not feasible in your case, you can also clear the session store in one of your views, by doing something like this:

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('clearsessions')
```

Comment: The thing is I'm not interested in cleaning up the `Session` table. As mentioned in the documentation, this can be done with a cron job.

What I want to do is to have a **trigger** that gets activated whenever a session `s` arrives to a point where `s.expire_date - timezone.now() < 0`. Sadly it does not seem to be as straighforward as I thought, so I think I will go with a Celery task that checks every 2min whether `Session.objects.filter(expire_data__lt=timezone.now())` returns something, then process the data and finally make a `clearsessions`.

Comment: Using the pre_delete signal on Session model let you act immediately on users that perform an explicit logout (without even waiting two minutes). Clearing the session store with a cron job (or even with a Celery task) let you delete expired Session objects for users who did not logout explicitly (e.g. closing the browser), activating again the pre_delete signal.

Comment: I am precisely interested in getting noticed of the sessions that have expired but that were not explicitly deleted by a user logout. Thus writing a Celery task that does both (filtering expired session, process the data and cleanup the table) is easier to maintain IMHO. I mean, `pre_delete` is not gonna get triggered unless I ask to.

Comment: Ok. Now I see your point. I think the celery task that periodically check the session store is the best solution.